# How to use cytoscape-popper extension of cytoscape in Angular 6?

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to use `cytoscape-popper` and/or `cytoscape-qtip` (whichever works) extension of `cytoscape` in `angular 6`.

I have used the following to import and use:

```
import popper from 'cytoscape-popper';
import qt from 'cytoscape-qtip';

_.use(require('cytoscape-popper'));
_.use(require('cytoscape-qtip'));
```

However, when I use `this.cy.popper()`, it doesn't compile saying that `popper` is not the function of type Core.

If I change the type of `cy` as `any` instead of `cytoscape.Core`, the code compiles however it doesn't show the expected result.

How to use these extensions in `angular`?

Comment: Hi, did you register the extension in cytoscape (like this: cy.use('cytoscape-popper')?               Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hi Stephan, I have imported cytoscape like (import * as _ from 'cytoscape'). Hence in the above code snippet, I am using _.use(require('cytoscape-popper')). I have also tried _.use('cytoscape-popper') which doesn't show any difference.
Moreover, it shows a red mark when using this.cy.popper(), saying popper is not a function for type Core. I am using chrome browser.

Comment: Stephan, do you have a working code snippet/project, where I can look and try to find the error I am making?

Comment: unfortunately not, I am using cytoscape and some extensions without angular, but I had similar issues in the past, however, I found [this article](http://johnnyflinn.github.io/ngCytoscape/#/gettingStarted) about ngCytoscape, which could help you with your task

Answer (score 0):

I used Angular CLI 7.x to generate a project and use the extension succesfully:

Cytoscape gives some information in "index.d.ts" file under ./node-modules/@types/cytoscape at the end of the file which should work for all extensions.

I am writing all steps below that I used to make 'cytoscape-panzoom' extension work. you can use the same steps for any other extension.

1. Install cytoscape using `npm install cytoscape`
2. Install cytoscape types using `npm install --save @types/cytoscape`
3. Install the root types `npm install @types/node --save-dev` (You may use --save see npm guide)
4. Make sure your tsconfig.json file has the following, otherwise
   add it (this is needed for 'require(...)' to work):

   ```
   "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ]
   ```
5. Install the cytoscape extension using 'npm install cytscape-panzoom'
   (in your case your extension name inplace of "cytoscape-panzoom", check the github for the extension you are using)
6. Add the  javascript and style files of the cytoscape extension; .js and .css (if applicable) to the relevant sections inside your 'angular.json' file:

   "styles": ["src/styles.css","./node_modules/cytoscape-panzoom/cytoscape.js-panzoom.css"],
   "scripts": ["./node_modules/cytoscape-panzoom/cytoscape-panzoom.js"]
7. Create a file in the root of your Angular project with an
   extension *.d.ts, in my case I used 'panzoom.d.ts' you can use the
   name of your cytoscape extension or simply typings.d.ts.
8. Put the following code in your .d.ts file and in place of
   "cytoscape-panzoom" you can use your extension's name:

   ```
       declare module 'cytoscape-panzoom' {
       const ext: cytoscape.Ext;
       export = ext;
     }
   ```
9. within the component write the following import code:

   ```
   var cyt = require ('cytoscape');
   var pz = require('cytoscape-panzoom');
   cyt.use(pz);
   ```

Now you can use the extension!

Usage sample:

```
...............

let cy_contianer = this.renderer.selectRootElement("#cy");
let cy = cyt({
container: cy_contianer,
layout: this.layout,
elements: this.elements,
minZoom: 0.3,
maxZoom: 5
});

  cy.style(this.style);

 var defaults = {
      zoomFactor: 0.05, // zoom factor per zoom tick
      zoomDelay: 45, // how many ms between zoom ticks       
      zoomInIcon: 'fa fa-plus',
      zoomOutIcon: 'fa fa-minus',
      resetIcon: 'fa fa-expand'

 // .... more settings here removed to make it short for sample
    };

    // HERE WE ARE USING THE EXTENSION THROUGH THE SAME cy OBJECT RETURNED BY cytoscape(..) function. 

    cy.panzoom(defaults);
```

Hope the answer helps.